# How to make a counter for multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I made a counter for one of my page like so:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `view` = `view`+1 WHERE pagename = 'http://local.login.com/main/article_view/24' ");

            $sql  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM viewcounter WHERE id = id");
            foreach ( $sql->result_array() as $row )
                {       
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $pagename = $row["pagename"];
                    $view = $row["view"];
            } echo 'SOMETHING';
```

As you noticed i have a table with id, pagename and views. when i visit the page it adds one to the view.
The question is: How can i make this work for, lets say, 20 pages? I don't want to add

`pagename = "http://local.login.com/main/article_view/24"`

and

`pagename = "http://local.login.com/main/article_view/25"`

because i don't like that.

I'm stuck help.

Comment: how else are you going to identify your pages? it's not like you'd have to hard-code the address of every page on your site. it's php... getting the requested address the script is running as is trivial.

Comment: the thing is, lets say i have reviews added every day and i want to keep a counter on everypage... so there isn't any way?

Comment: do an `insert ... on duplicate key set view=view+1` instead?

Comment: i found the perfect answer from Dieter i use this function $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and works great for what i need. thanks marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run your code when you enter a php page? Then you don't have to pass parameters and you could just get your url by using:

> $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

If that's what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The following may be what you're looking for. You can change `$i<20` to whatever number of iterations you want to run (ie `$i<100`), and you can change `24+$i` to start at whatever number you want (ie `1332+$i`)

```
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    $this->db->query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `view` = `view`+1 WHERE pagename = 'http://local.login.com/main/article_view/".(24+$i)."' ");
}

            $sql  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM viewcounter WHERE id = id");
            foreach ( $sql->result_array() as $row )
                {       
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $pagename = $row["pagename"];
                    $view = $row["view"];
            } echo 'SOMETHING';
```

Comment: what you did has logic but i get an error : syntax error, unexpected '.24' (T_DNUMBER).